# CINDER INITIALIZATION

Tags: visual-c++, cinder

``I am learning how to loadImage in cinder.

I used loadImage function defined in **ImageIo.h file**,
but When I build my code it gives the following error

```
c:\users\user\particle\src\particleapp.cpp(30): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'ParticleApp *' to 'cinder::app::AppBasic *'


1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

How to resolve it ?

Comment: It's hard to say how to fix it without seeing the code that causes it. There are a few different things that can cause C2440 errors. If you post the relevant section of your code someone might be able to give you a more concrete answer

Answer (score 1):

Trying to guess without seeing your code.
But have you added the parent class type to your ParticleApp class?

Where you declare 
class ParticleApp { ... }

you should do:
class ParticleApp : public cinder::app::AppBasic { ... }